# Broadcasting online camera

Tags: camera, streaming, live, broadcast

I have online camera which is using some IP address and port. I have also credentials to login into camera (login, password) and I want to broadcast video from device to my webpage. What I need to do it? Which tools should I use? Model of this webcam is ST_IP760.

Answer (score 0):

...and I found a solution (if anyone needs). Here is great website where you can post rtsp link and even embed player with your online camera to your website (but you need pay for this option; adding camera and broadcasting is free): https://ipcamlive.com/ .

Happy broadcasting :)